# Re-work functions with load external html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, load, external

My html document is have scripts.js file already. But i need re-work all functions in the scripts.js file with loading external html files.

```
$( "#loader" ).load( 'projects/project_01.html', function() {
  $.getScript( "js/scripts.js");
});
```

It is calling scripts file but functions not working again. How i can re-work all functions in the scripts.js file with each load new files?

Answer (score 0):

if `scripts.js` is already loaded you probably just need to do something in that file like:

```
// group content funcionality into function(s)
function contentInit(){
   $('button').doSomething();
   $('input').change(doSomethingElse);    
}

// initial page load
$(document).ready(function(){
   // for initial page content
   contentInit();

   $( "#loader" ).load( 'projects/project_01.html', function() {
       // for ajax loaded content
       contentInit();
   });
});
```

Now you just call functions that already exist after you load new content